# Why doesn't "double" work in the options list of a scope?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

An example document:

```
\documentclass[convert={size=320}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[line width = 2pt, red]
        \foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4} {
            \draw (\x, 0) -- (\x, 5);
        }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [ line width = 2pt,
                    color = green!80,
                    double distance = 2pt,
                    double = blue          % <--- This doesn't have any effect
                    ]
        \draw (0, 4) -- (5, 4);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [ line width = 2pt,
                    color = green!80,
                    double distance = 2pt,
                    every path/.style = {double = blue}
                    ]
        \draw (0, 3) -- (5, 3);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [ line width = 2pt,
                    color = green!80,
                    every path/.style = { double distance = 2pt,
                                          double = blue
                                          }]
        \draw (0, 2) -- (5, 2);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} [every path/.style = { line width = 2pt,
                                         color = green!80,
                                         double distance = 2pt,
                                         double = blue
                                         }]
        \draw (0, 1) -- (5, 1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I don't understand this behaviour. Why do all the other options in the scope options list apply to the drawn paths, but not "double"? The other options can be put in the scope options list or in the `every path/.style` options list within the scope options list, and they'll work either way. But not "double". The PGF/TikZ manual, extensive though it is, did not illuminate things for me.

Comment: It doesn’t work in the same way like `draw` (or `fill`) wouldn’t work there. Both add an mode to the current path (all modes are reset at the start of the path after which the `every path` style is executed). All other options just set a specific setting.

Comment: I would be interested to know the part of the PGF/TikZ manual, or other resources, that I should read to understand better what you mean by the word "mode" in your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn’t work in the same way as giving the option `draw` or `fill` as an option to a scope will not stroke or fill all paths in tho scope. Given as an option to a scope, they just set the color in the event a path uses those options without a value.

In your case

```
\draw[double] (0, 4) -- (5, 4);
```

would use the `blue` from the `scope`’s setting.

The manual says to the option `draw=<color>`:

> Although this option is normally used on paths to indicate that the path should be drawn, it also makes sense to use the option with a `{scope}` or `{tikzpicture}` environment. However, this will not cause all paths to be drawn. Instead, this just sets the `<color>` to be used for drawing paths inside the environment.

While the manual doesn’t say much regarding this topic about any other “actions” on a path, this also applies—besides `draw` and `double`—to

- `fill`s,
- `clip`s,
- `use as a bounding box` (which is very similar to a `clip`, just without the clipping),
- `tips`<sup>3.0.0</sup> and
- `shade`s.

The manual does again explain this behavior for both fadings, the

- `path fading=<name>`:

  > This option tells TikZ that the current path should be faded with the fading `<name>`. If no `<name>` is given, the `<name>` set for the whole scope is used. Similarly to options like `draw` or `fill`, this option is reset for each path, so you have to add it to each path that should be faded.

  and
- the `scope fading=<fading>` (paradoxical as it seems):

  > […] [J]ust as for `path fading`, providing the `scope fading` option with a `{scope}` only sets the name of the fading to be used. You have to explicitly provide the `scope fading` with a path to actually install a fading.

Also `path picture` (a very special and custom filling of a path) is an “action on a path” and abides these rules:

> As with other keys like `fill` or `draw` this option needs to be given on a path, setting the `path picture` outside a path has no effect (the path picture is cleared at the beginning of each path).

With these words (“cleared at the beginning of each path”) we turn to the source of TikZ, the file `tikz.code.tex`. Each of these mentioned options include a call to `\tikz@addmode` which appends its argument to `\tikz@mode`. In the (internal) definition of `\path`, this macro is emptied:

```
\let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
```

(The `every path` style is executed afterwards.) When `;` is encountered (and the path has been constructed) all these modes are falsed:

```
\let\tikz@path@picture=\pgfutil@empty%
\tikz@mode@fillfalse%
\tikz@mode@drawfalse%
\tikz@mode@tipsfalse% (3.0.0)
\tikz@mode@doublefalse%
\tikz@mode@clipfalse%
\tikz@mode@boundaryfalse% (“use as bounding box”)
\tikz@mode@fade@pathfalse%
\tikz@mode@fade@scopefalse%
```

and the saved modes are installed:

```
\tikz@mode% installs the mode settings
```

and the magic begins.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed explanation. I appreciate the in-depth discussion of what a "mode" means and how it interacts with paths and scopes.